# Did @@IDENTITY return last inserted row for one user or for all users?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

@@IDENTITY return last inserted identity values for every table, so for all scopes.

I have app that allow users insert data in database for all day. On the other side, I have some scripts for some data imports where I use @@IDENTITY in cursor to fetch every row identity and place it in some log table.

Now, will it be possible to @@IDENTITY to pick identity from users inserts, and to make mess in my log table?

Comment: Microsoft have written some pretty decent [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx), which includes a discussion of `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY` and `IDENT_CURRENT`.

Comment: Regarding the question in the title `@@IDENTITY` does not return values from other users' sessions. The distinction with `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is RE: visibility of values inserted across scopes within a session.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)

> Returns the last identity value inserted into an identity column in
>   the same scope. A scope is a module: a stored procedure, trigger,
>   function, or batch. Therefore, two statements are in the same scope if
>   they are in the same stored procedure, function, or batch.

(the instances where you need to use anything but `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` are few).

As `@Damien_The_Unbeliever` pointed out, the above link includes a discussion of the uses/benefits/drawbacks to using `@@IDENTITY`, `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` and `IDENT_CURRENT`

Answer (score 0):

I hope following will give you answer. I think your case you should use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

**@@IDENTITY**

It returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

Let me explain this... suppose we create an insert trigger on table which inserts a row in another table with generate an identity column, then @@IDENTITY returns that identity record which is created by trigger.

**SCOPE_IDENTITY**

It returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.

Let me explain this... suppose we create an insert trigger on table which inserts a row in another table with generate an identity column, then SCOPE_IDENTITY result is not affected but if a trigger or a user defined function is affected on the same table that produced the value returns that identity record then SCOPE_IDENTITY returns that identity record which is created by trigger or a user defined function.

**IDENT_CURRENT**

It returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

In other words, we can say it is not affected by scope and session, it only depends on a particular table and returns that table related identity value which is generated in any session or scope.

ref taken from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103610/Difference-between-IDENTITY-SCOPE_IDENTITY-IDENT_C)